# When filtering, never throw away information you don't need to

Tags: unix-philosophy

In [this text](https://homepage.cs.uri.edu/%7Ethenry/resources/unix_art/ch01s08.html), the author says

> When filtering, never throw away information you don't need to

What does it mean in the context of applying UNIX philosophy?

Comment: This feels more like a theology question / exegesis exercise than a technical question :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look [a bit later in the text](https://homepage.cs.uri.edu/%7Ethenry/resources/unix_art/ch11s06.html), where the author discusses what they call "The Filter Pattern," they expand on this by saying the following:

> When filtering, never throw away information you don't need to. This, too, increases the odds that your filter will someday be useful as an input to other programs. Information you discard is information that no later stage in a pipeline can use.

The author exemplifies "The Filter Pattern" by mentioning `grep` and `tr`.  These two utilities are what they call "`cat`-like." Apart from performing their task, they do not delete or otherwise modify the data received on their input stream but instead reproduce it unmodified on their output stream.  Some implementations of, e.g., `grep` do not adhere to these guidelines strictly but modify the data by inserting color escape codes; these implementations, however, still don't *delete* data unnecessarily (like removing unprintable characters, truncating the output at some arbitrary width, limiting the number of returned lines or bytes in some way by default, or in some other way *trying to be smarter than the user*).